# Is this a bug of Kotlin REPL?

Tags: kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

I can define a value in Kotlin REPL like this(recursively) without getting an error:

```
val s: String = s
```

And now I get an 's' with the type of NotNull but the value of null.
And I can do something with this `NotNull` value with a NPE:

```
>>> val s: String = s

>>> s.length
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You can try it on your own Kotlin REPL, it works every time.

I am using Kotlin version 1.1.2-3.

Comment: The REPL works by turning local variables into members of a class that represents the state at the END of the line being executed.  So the variable `s` is created as a member with `null` value and then later set to its own value (still `null`), which is why the code compiles.  It is not truly checking the code in context, but checking the code against previous lines and current values set in the current line.  So there are other cases that will fail.   But a bug is a bug, please search for it and if not there report the bug:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: And please note the bug here  so other readers can track its state.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find an open issue for it, so I created this one https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18052

Comment: Update: it's been marked as a duplicate, it's being tracked here instead https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug.

```
val s: String = s
print(s.length)
```

This code compiled successfully but at runtime, it's giving an error.

> Error:  Unresolved reference: s

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a bug of REPL.

In the REAL Kotlin file, it will complain as a "Unresolve reference"

Sorry, I cannot post a img, but you could try at your IDE.

I am using the IntelliJ-IDEA 2017.1.3